# Use Facelets composition without any template

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I watched the [facelet template example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/) and I could see the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/JSF%20Facelets%20Tools%20Tutorial.html), too, in both cases I can see the tuts make using `<ui:composition template="/layout.xhtml">` **with template support only**; But is there a way **not to include template** if I want some a very simple facelet for example?

I tried to ignore the template attribute but then I have `java.lang.StackOverflowError` being thrown :( So the jsf 2.0 makes me to have templates to be included anyway...

So my question is... is there a way writing facelets without templates references?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, certainly. Just use the same XHTML composition as the master template `/layout.xhtml` itself, but then **without** any `<ui:insert>`. Instead, just put the desired content straight in there.

For example, `/page.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Some title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Some heading</h1>
        <p>Plain Facelets page without template!</p>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Open this directly as `/page.xhtml` in browser.